# When running gradle task inside map loop the task is running only after the script

Tags: gradle, build

I am using a docker plugin to build my docker images,
I have a project with multiply services but it is a monolete so I have a single build.gradle file.
What I'm trying to do is build all the images using a map loop,
but when building the project only the last element in the map is being built.

These is the relevant parts of the **build.gradle** file:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'maven'
    id 'distribution'
    id 'maven-publish'
    //docker-plugin
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.25.0'
}

group = 'com.company.scheduler'
version '4.0.0-SNAPSHOT'


//Handle release version scenario 
def PublishedVersion
def buildNumber
if (version ==~ /(?s).*SNAPSHOT.*/) {  //Check if SNAPSHOT/Release version
    if ("$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER" == null) {buildNumber = '0'} else {buildNumber = "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER"}
    PublishedVersion = version
} else {
    if ("$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER" == null) {buildNumber = '0'} else {buildNumber = "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER"}
    PublishedVersion = version + '-' + buildNumber
}

mainClassName = 'com.company.scheduler'

dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.coralogix.sdk', name: 'coralogix-sdk', version: '2.0.3'
}

def serviceOptionMap =   [ "utility-meters": "utility_meters_import_plugins",
                           "weather":        "weather_importer"
]

serviceOptionMap.each { k, v ->
    docker {
            def service_id="${k}"
            def artifact_start_script="${v}"
            println 'artifact_start_script: ' + artifact_start_script
            println 'service_id: ' + service_id
            name "47957039666.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/panpwr/service-gradle/${service_id}:$PublishedVersion"
            //if (version ==~ /(?s).*SNAPSHOT.*/) {tag "$version", "47957039666.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/panpwr/ev/${project.name}:latest"}
            copySpec.from("build/distributions").into(".")
            dockerfile file("${rootProject.projectDir}/Dockerfile")
            buildArgs([ARTIFACT_ID: "${service_id}", PANPWR_VERSION: "$PublishedVersion", ARTIFACT_START_SCRIPT: "$artifact_start_script"])
            labels(["service-name": "${service_id}", "service-version": "$PublishedVersion"])
            pull false //TODO: change to true
            noCache false
            println 'built docker image: ' + service_id
        }
}
```

This is the build output:

```
> Configure project :scheduled-tasks
artifact_start_script: utility_meters_import_plugins
service_id: utility-meters
built docker image: utility-meters
artifact_start_script: weather_importer
service_id: weather
built docker image: weather

> Task :scheduled-tasks:dockerClean
> Task :scheduled-tasks:dockerPrepare
> Task :scheduled-tasks:docker

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
10:16:39 AM: Task execution finished 'docker'.
```

And when I check  my local images I can see only the second image:

```
$ docker images | grep gradle
47957039666.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/panpwr/service-gradle/weather           4.0.0-SNAPSHOT      729a926206ed        20 hours ago        1.11GB
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this plugin [doesn't support building multiple images](https://github.com/palantir/gradle-docker/issues/148),
So I ended up creating a sub-module to each service that only creates docker images using this plugin.
So this is pretty much the structure:

```
├── Dockerfile
├── app1
│   └── build.gradle
├── app2
│   └── build.gradle
├── gradle
│   └── wrapper
│       ├── gradle-wrapper.jar
│       └── gradle-wrapper.properties
├── gradle-user-home
├── gradlew
├── build.gradle
```

And this is the simple **gradle.build** for the submodules:

```
plugins {
    //docker-plugin
    id 'com.palantir.docker' version '0.25.0'
}

version '4.0.0-SNAPSHOT'


//Handle release version scenario 
def PublishedVersion
def buildNumber
if (version ==~ /(?s).*SNAPSHOT.*/) {  //Check if SNAPSHOT/Release version
    if ("$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER" == null) {buildNumber = '0'} else {buildNumber = "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER"}
    PublishedVersion = version
} else {
    if ("$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER" == null) {buildNumber = '0'} else {buildNumber = "$System.env.BUILD_NUMBER"}
    PublishedVersion = version + '-' + buildNumber
}

docker {
    name "47957039666.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/panpwr/service-gradle/${project.name}:$PublishedVersion"
    copySpec.from("${rootProject.projectDir}/scheduled-tasks/build/distributions").into(".")
    dockerfile file("${rootProject.projectDir}/Dockerfile")
    buildArgs([ARTIFACT_ID: "${project.name}", PANPWR_VERSION: "$PublishedVersion", ARTIFACT_START_SCRIPT: "${project.name}"])
    labels(["service-name": "${project.name}", "service-version": "$PublishedVersion"])
    pull true
    noCache false
    println 'built docker image: ' + project.name
}


publishing {
    publications {
        dockerPublication(MavenPublication) {
            from components.docker
            artifactId project.name + "-docker"
        }
    }
}
```

And running the docker task on the root project creates all the docker images:

```
./gradlew clean build docker -g gradle-user-home
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a common misconception of how Gradle works. While the actual build script is evaluated in an imperative way (like a common Groovy script), the task concept is somehow declarative:

Gradle distinguishes between the *configuration phase* and the *execution phase*. During *configuration phase*, the build script is evaluated and the tasks are configured. During *execution phase*, all **required** tasks are executed. Required tasks are tasks that are specified using the command line and their (transitive) dependencies.

This misconception often becomes apparent when build script authors use `println` to understand how tasks are executed, but all `println` statements are evaluated during *configuration phase*.

---

Lets take a look at your concrete problem. You have a loop and inside that loop you have something like `docker { ... }`. In your title it says "running gradle task inside map loop", so you think that `docker { ... }` runs a task, but this is not correct. It is correct, that `docker` is a task in your example, but your code won't run (or execute) the task, your code just configures the task. After the build script is evaluated, Gradle will setup a task graph from all tasks and their configured task dependencies (`dependsOn` statements). Using this task graph, Gradle will determine the required tasks and execute them.

Now, knowing that the task `docker` is not executed but only configured, the problem with your code is pretty obvious: The second configuration of the task overwrites the first configuration. By the way, this has nothing to do with the loop, you could just apply the two configurations subsequently and get the same result:

```
docker {
    name "first"
    dockerfile file("first/Dockerfile")
}

docker {
    name "second"
    dockerfile file("second/Dockerfile")
}
```

The actual problem with your approach however is completely different: In Gradle, every task will be executed **only once** in a build. This means, you won't be able to run the task `docker` twice to create two docker images. You either need to configure the task so that it creates two docker images in one execution, or somehow generate two different tasks of the same type. I'm not familiar with the plugin you are using, so I don't know whether it's capable of one of those two approaches.

You may take a look at the [Gradle Docker Plugin](https://bmuschko.github.io/gradle-docker-plugin/) by Benjamin Muschko, that allows you to create as many tasks of type `DockerBuildImage` as you need.